# Examples of non uniformly convergent probability density functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm looking to find examples of a sequence of probability density functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ where $f$ is also a pdf, but the convergence is not uniform.

Does a $\text{Unif}(0,1-1/n)$ work here (converging to a $\text{Unif}(0,1)$).  I have to admit that my conceptual understanding is a little bit weak here.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your example works. In your example, you will have $$f_n = \frac{n}{n-1} \chi_{[0,1-1/n]}, \,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\,\, f = \chi_{[0,1]},$$ where $\chi_A$ denotes the indicator function of $A$. Thus for $n\ge 2$, $$f_n - f = \frac{1}{n-1} \chi_{[0,1-1/n)} - \chi_{[1-1/n,1]}.$$ Thus $$\|f_n-f\|_\infty = 1 \,\,\,\,\, \text{ for all } n \ge 2$$ since $\lvert f_n - f \rvert = 1$ on the set $[1-1/n,1].$ This shows that convergence is not uniform, since $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} \lvert f_n(x) - f(x) \rvert \not\to 0$.

However, for any $p \in [1,\infty)$ we see $$\|f_n - f\|^p_{L^p} = \int_0^{1-1/n} \frac{1}{(n-1)^p} dx + \int_{1-1/n}^1 dx = \frac 1 {n(n-1)^{p-1}} + \frac 1 n \to 0 \,\,\,\,\, \text {as} \,\,\,\, n \to \infty.$$ Thus $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ for any $p \in [1,\infty)$. This shows that $f_n \to f$ in probability as well, and it is fairly straightforward to see that we also have $f_n \to f$ almost surely.